# Modifying this GoL implementation to make it sensible to clicks on the corner of the array

Tags: manipulate, eventhandler, event-detection

I'm interested in modifying this interactive implementation of the Game of Life

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RealTimeSimulationOfTheGameOfLife/

to make it sensible to click events on the borders of the array. The array doesn't update when clicked in elements in the first/last rows and columns. I haven't been able to find out why.

[image]

Try running the code below.

```
Manipulate[
 Refresh[
  If[oldlen != len || oldp != p,
   oldlen = len;
   oldp = p;
   updating = False;
   config = Table[If[RandomReal[] < p, 1, 0], {len}, {len}];
   t = 0
   ];
  If[
   updating || onestep,
   t++;
   onestep = False;
   config = 
    Last[CellularAutomaton[{224, {2, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 
          2}}}, {1, 1}}, If[bg, {config, 0}, config], {{0, 1}}]];
   If[config == {},
         config = {{0}}
    ]
   ];
  EventHandler[
   Dynamic[
    ArrayPlot[Reverse@config,
     PlotLabel -> Row[{Style["t", Italic], " = " <> ToString[t]}],
     ImageSize -> {400, 400},
     AspectRatio -> Automatic,
      Mesh -> True]], 
   "MouseClicked" :> (If[
        1 < #[[1]] < Length[config] && 
         1 < #[[2]] < Length[First[config]], 
        config[[#[[2]], #[[1]]]] = 1 - config[[#[[2]], #[[1]]]]] &)[
     Ceiling@MousePosition["Graphics"]]]

  , UpdateInterval -> If[updating, 0, Infinity]
  ]
 ,
 {{updating, False, "run simulation"}, {True, False}},
 Button["update one step", onestep = True, ImageSize -> Medium],
 Button["reset", updating = False; 
  config = Table[If[RandomReal[] < p, 1, 0], {len}, {len}]; t = 0, 
  ImageSize -> Small],
 {{bg, False, "infinite space"}, {True, False}},
 {{len, 10, "edge length"}, 10, 200, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{oldlen, 50}, ControlType -> None},
 {{p, 0.1, "initial density"}, 0, 1, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
  ImageSize -> Tiny},
 {{oldp, 0.1}, ControlType -> None},
 {{t, 0}, ControlType -> None},
 {{config, Table[If[RandomReal[] < p, 1, 0], {50}, {50}]}, 
  ControlType -> None},
 {{onestep, False}, ControlType -> None},
 ControlPlacement -> Left,
 TrackedSymbols :> {updating, onestep, config, len, t, bg, p}, 
 AutorunSequencing -> {3, 5}, SynchronousUpdating -> True
 ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<=` instead of `<` here:

```
"MouseClicked" :> (If[
     1 <= #[[1]] <= Length[config] && 
      1 <= #[[2]] <= Length[First[config]], 
     config[[#[[2]], #[[1]]]] = 1 - config[[#[[2]], #[[1]]]]] &)[
  Ceiling@MousePosition["Graphics"]]
```